# Action not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to show a simple HTML template, so I added a new empty action to my controller:

```
def calulator
end
```

And created the view calculator.html.erb . Then added a link to it:

```
<%= link_to 'Calculator', {:controller => "mycontroller", :action => "calculator"} %>
```

When I click it my log shows the following error:

```
ActionController::UnknownAction (No action responded to show. Actions: calculator, create, destroy, edit, index, new, and update):
```

Why is looking for a "**show**" action ? I have map.resources for the controller, as I done it with scaffolding

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add a custom route pointing to the action 'calculator'.
Something like this:

```
map.connect 'mycontroller/calculator', :controller => 'mycontroller', :action => 'calculator'
```

Comment: That works great. I figured out that the line must be **before** map.resources line, when common sense told me it should be after. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can define members and collections for resources.

```
map.resources :samples, :member => {:calculator => :get}
```

Member means that it relates to an instance of the resources. For example /samples/1/calculator. If it doesn't relate to an instance you can define it for the collection and can be access via /samples/calculator.

```
map.resources :samples, :collection => {:calculator => :get}
```

This also creates a helper method `calculator_samples_path` for the collection and `calculator_sample_path(sample)` for a member. For more on this have a look at [Railscast Episode 35](http://railscasts.com/episodes/35-custom-rest-actions).

Answer (score 0):

You are getting *No action responded to show* because you have the controller routed as `map.resources`.  When you do that, rails sets up several routes for you.  One of which is `show`, which maps every *get* request matching */mycontroller/somevalue* to the `show` action with *somevalue* as the id (`params[:id]`).  In `mycontroller`, there is no `show` action, as seen in the error message.

To fix this, Nils or Trevoke's answer should work just fine.

[map.resources documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Resources.html#M000522)